# Group my SQL float values by range

Tags: android, sql, group-by, simplecursoradapter

I have a cursor with a float value describing my people weight in kg.

So all my people in my database have this look:

```
NAME - WEIGHT:
John: 85.3
Michael:80.3
Lisa 58.2
Christopher: 75.0
```

What I want to do is to display them in a ListView by weight range.

```
"50-60": 1 people
"60-70": 1 people
"70-80": 2 people
"80-90": 0 people
```

I plan to use a ListView with a SimpleCursorAdapter, but I don't know how to group them...

Thank a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
select
sum(case when weight > 60 and weight <= 70 then 1 else 0 end) as weight1,
sum(case when weight > 60 and weight <= 80 then 1 else 0 end) as weight2
from myTable
```

Comment: Thatś great, but I cannot use that in a CursorAdaptor because cursor size == 1, is there a way to improve that? To fill a ListView with the result, I will need to recreate an array, right?

Comment: Don't know the answer to that I'm afraid, only have minimal Android experience. I'd guess you either need to do a pivot (which I don't think is supported) or spit out the columns into an array/list/other.